# Retrieve width of element while rendering in the return statement with inline JSX

Tags: reactjs

I have an element whose width I would like to calculate, and then iterate however many times are necessary to duplicate the element and take up at least the viewports full width.

The issue I am having is I am not able to grab the width with the style of inline JSX rendering I am using. I get an error in the useEffect that the refWidth is null, even when I set it as a dependency.

Is there a way to do the calculation and render the correct number of times without having to add the element first to the return statement, get its width, and then append the necessary number of elements?

[CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/render-based-on-width-q7rdl2?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the width of an element in inline JSX rendering, you can use the useLayoutEffect hook.

```
  import { useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const windowWidth = 1920;
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [numberOfItems, setNumberOfItems] = useState(0);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current && setNumberOfItems(Math.ceil(windowWidth / ref.current.clientWidth));
  }, [windowWidth]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2 ref={ref}>hello</h2>
      {Array.from({ length: numberOfItems }, (_, i) => (
        <h2 key={i}>
          hello
        </h2>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`useLayoutEffect` hook ensures that the width calculation happens after the element has been rendered, allowing for more accurate results.

Comment: this removes the error, but it doesn't render anything.

[forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/render-based-on-width-forked-76d62j?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @rnrh you are right the useRef for the element <h2>  is being assigned to multiple elements within the loop. so the solution is to remove ref={ref} and create a new element  <h2 ref={ref}>hello</h2> before/ after the loop